# What does this query mean?

Tags: sql

I'm reading a book about SQL.

In that book, I saw strange query below:

```
SELECT * into mycustomer from customer WHERE 1=2
```

In this query, what is "WHERE 1=2" ?

Comment: As everybody said below, the condition is always false. I've seen that technique used with dynamic SQL as a way to get a descriptor for the columns in the query - but you do not then have an INTO clause.

Comment: Jonathan: The INTO clause is used to create a new table `mycustomer` by querying `customer`. In this case no rows will be returned, so an empty table will be created. This is an idiom for copying a table structure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Usually used to copy structure of one table to into another, as in your case.

```
SELECT * INTO mycustomer FROM customer WHERE 1=2
```

This code creates an identical structure of table `Customer` in your new table `MyCustomer`. 
**Note** that in SQL Server, the constraints are not copied; so probably you would need to recreate the constraints.

Answer (score 3):

`1=2` will always be `false`.

This is a way to specify a `WHERE` clause that will always evaluate to `false`.

A similar thing is `WHERE 1=1` which always evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days when I was using classic ASP, I used the "WHERE 1=2" structure to retrieve the column definitions of the table and not its contents. Nowadays there are better ways of retrieving column definitions by using an object-relation mapping framework.

My guess is that the book you are reading is slightly outdated, or the context of this query is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 1=2
```

Is impossible so that condition will always be false. Is it a typo? Maybe it is to clear a load of variables? As SELECT INTO will put all columns into @COLUMNNAME vars

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing but just like a SQL injecttion in your case it will always false if 1=1 than its true and will return all Customers data